# Equivalent definition of brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm having a question about this characterization of Brownian Motion :

**Theorem :** 
If a process : $\big( X_t \big)_{t\geq 0}$ satisfies these conditions,

1. $\big( X_t \big)_{t\geq 0}$  is a Gaussian process,
2. For all $t,s\geq 0$ : $$\mathbb{E}(X_t)=0\quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{C}ov(X_s,X_t) = \min(s,t)$$
3. $\big( X_t \big)_{t\geq 0}$ is a continuous process (their paths are a.s. continuous)

then it's a Brownian motion.

---

The definition was given as this :

**Definition :** 
Let a process : $\big( X_t \big)_{t\geq 0}$ satisfies these conditions,

1. $X_0 \underset{a.s.}{=} 0$
2. For all $t>s\geq 0$ : the increment $X_t-X_s$ is independent of the $\sigma$-Algebra :
   $$ \mathcal{F}^X_s = \sigma\bigg( X_u, \ u\leq s \bigg) $$
3. For all $t > s\geq 0$ : $$X_t - X_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$$
4. $\big( X_t \big)_{t\geq 0}$ is a continuous process (their paths are a.s. continuous)

then we call it a Brownian motion.

---

I'm looking for a proof of the theorem

Comment: What's your question then?

Comment: i wanna proof of it

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have problem in the second asumption (the independence of increments), in fact i can show :
1 - $X_0=0$ a.s using the $Var(X_0) = 0$  
3 - Since $V = (X_s,X_t)$ is a guassian vector, then $X_t - X_s=a^T\times V$ is normal, and we calculate its variance using $a^TVar(V)a$ that will give us $t-s$
4 - It's itself an asumption.

Comment: Seems you have made some good progress. It would be useful to edit into your question which conditions you have been able to prove both ways.